# ListViewWebPart

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using listviewwebpart to display contents of SPFolder (subfolder inside a list) to display its contents.
Beolw is the code to implement the same :

```
  protected override void CreateChildControls()
  {
    try
    {
      base.CreateChildControls();

      webPart = new ListViewWebPart();

      using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
      using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
        clientName = DataLogic.Client.GetClientName(Constants.Session.Client_ClientID);
        var library = web.Lists["Account"];
        webPart.ListName = library.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
        webPart.ListId = library.ID;   
        SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("/Account/" + clientName);
        if (folder.Item != null)
        {
          SPContentTypeId folderctid = folder.Item.ContentType.Id;

          //set the folder url
          SetPrivateFieldValue(webPart, "rootFolder", folder.Url);
          SetPrivateFieldValue(webPart, "folderCtId", folderctid.ToString());
          webPart.ListViewXml = library.DefaultView.GetViewXml();            
          webPart.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
          this.mainSec.Controls.Add(webPart);
        }
        else
        {
          lblWarning.Text = "There is no document library associated with client " + clientName;
        }           

      }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
  }

  private static void SetPrivateFieldValue(object obj, string fieldName, string val)
  {
    FieldInfo fi = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    fi.SetValue(obj, val);
  }
```

The contents display correctly but the toolbar is the parent list's toolbar and not the folder's toolbar.
How can i modify the toolbar context to load the context of the spfolder?